# where has my img gone?

Tags: html, css, image

Can anyone advise why I can't get my image to appear? This is driving me crazy!

Below is the code - maybe i've missed a colon or something? or not sure if DTD strict has anything to do with it?

Problem is that the background is coloured as its supposed to, and the alt name shows, but the image is missing???

Style......

```
div#topbox {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #FFFFCC;
}
img
{
float:right;
}
```

The div html code in the body looks something like this.....

```
<div id="topbox">
  <h2>Next Fashion</h2>
  <img src="fashion5.jpg" width="200" height="150" alt="Fur Coat" />
  <p>The following design is the latest in fur: minx is out, New Zealand possum fur is in!: </p>
</div>
```

Any idea's before I go mad and start telling everyone that demons can posses computers?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mhUfc/ it's here on this fiddle with your code.

Comment: provide a demo link please

Comment: Open the console, in Chrome press `CTRL + SHFT + I`, and go to network - See if that picture is being downloaded.

Comment: check your img url src http://jsfiddle.net/SxxWV/30/

Comment: Check that path of image is same as generated in inspect-elements

Comment: Seen as it seems to work in the fiddle check the file path of your image.  I can't imagine it's in the same directory as your html/php file?  Should the line not be something like:

`<img src="images/fashion5.jpg" width="200" height="150" alt="Fur Coat" />`

Comment: Yeah you sure dont have the image inside cause for me your code works mate. http://jsfiddle.net/7TENL/

Comment: Thanks everyone! Ive just checked, and it shows in Chrome, firefox and opera.... just not in IE! so cant be the file path. Any idea's why IE wont show it?

Answer (score 2):

Try giving absolute path in img src like

```
   img src="https://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/fashion5.png"
```

instead of

```
   img src="fashion5.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked writting the full path of the image, probably you haven't the image in the same directory than the file. As our friend vengets said: That's the error

HTML

```
 <div id="topbox">
  <h2>Next Fashion</h2>
 <img src="http://www.apicius.es/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/IMG-20120714-009211.jpg" width="200" height="150" alt="Fur Coat" />
  <p>The following design is the latest in fur: minx is out, New Zealand possum fur is in!:      </p>
 </div>
```

[Here it works](http://jsfiddle.net/qwqyq/)